# How to create a dynamic RAW Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to create a dynamic Raw Queryset.

By default a raw queryset looks like:

```
qs = self.raw(
            'SELECT DISTINCT ON(P.slug) P.id, P.slug, P.company_id, I.image, 
            'FROM product AS P ' ....
```

It is possible to create the queryset using conditions. I'm not referring to database conditions like `Where`, but python conditions like `if`

Something like:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT ON(P.slug) P.id, P.slug, P.company_id, I.image, 
                'FROM product AS P ' # if var_a Limit 20 else where P.id = var_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use simple python if/else:

```
query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ON(P.slug) P.id, P.slug, P.company_id, I.image FROM product AS P '
params = []
if var_a:
    query += 'LIMIT 20'
else:
    query += 'WHERE P.id = %s'
    params.append(var_b)

qs = self.raw(query, params)
```